# Mavericks Mail will not save preferences

Tags: mail.app, email, macos, preferences

I have the updated version of Mail, and still having Gmail problems, but one problem at a time here… Currently the headache is that it will not save any preferences: window layout, junk mail filtering off, etc. Every time I quit and re-launch it is back to default settings. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the permissions correct on the relevant Mail folders: `~/Library/Mail` & `~/Library/Containers/Mail`?

Comment: I have repaired permissions and it did not find anything, so I assume those are correct.

Comment: Are you referring to repairing permissions with Disk Utility or through the ACL tool on the Recovery HD? The former will only fix permissions for system files, not preference files or anything else in your home folder.

Comment: I used Disk Utility as normal. I will use the Recovery process now -- I wasn't aware of that -- and will report back. Thanks.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you. I will now remember that this feature exists.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that all the permissions are correct on your home folder.
You can use the ACL tool on the Recovery HD to do this:

1. Boot into the Recovery HD using ⌘R.
2. Run `resetpassword` in Terminal (available from Utilities → Terminal).
3. Select your account from the drop-down list.
4. Click the Reset button for **Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs**.