# Fixing broken Messages on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, messages

I managed to break my Messages install trying to get it to work on my MacBook Air by deleting Library files that worked with it. Now when I try to open messages I get the error

> An internal Messages error occurred.
>
> > There was a problem with Messages. You need to quit and open Messages again.

Can I just copy Library files from another one of my computers running OS X? Or is this the sort of thing that I need to reinstall the OS for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, copying the files from another computer should be fine**, providing both computers have the same version of Messages.

There is a certain amount of leniency with this though, depending on where the files are that you deleted. For example, files in your home folder are expected to be backward-compatible since if you've upgraded your OS then it must know how to update the files.

Also, once you've copied the files, make sure you set the permissions correctly…

- If you've copied files to /Library, use Disk Utility to repair permissions.
- If you've copied files to ~/Library, [use the ACL tool on the Recovery HD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110346/37797).