# Backup and Restore Apple Messages on macOS

Tags: macos, backup, restore, messages

Is there some means of saving your Messages history on OS X and copying it to a new system without doing a full restore from a Time Machine back up?

Doing some searching, I found the below and tried this approach in a virtual machine copy of Mavericks without much luck.

> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5948332

Despite copying the files to their respective locations on the fresh install and adjusting permissions, the new installation version of Messages never seems to import/recognize the history from my current system.

To ensure my permissions were okay, I also found

> [Mavericks Mail will not save preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110334/mavericks-mail-will-not-save-preferences/110346#110346)

which was linked to by

> [Fixing broken Messages on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113955/fixing-broken-messages-on-os-x-mavericks)

but this also did not result in Messages importing/using the copied history.  Both instances of Mavericks are using Messages 8.0

Comment: It is high time that Apple fixes that product and provides us with a means to undo a conversation removal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to import message history from a Time Machine backup onto a new machine without a full restore from a Time Machine backup. This was tested on 10.10 but should work for at least 10.9 as well.

1. Take a full Time Machine backup of the new system.
2. Quit Messages.app.
3. Remove all of the following files and directories on the new system:

   - *~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iChat/*
   - *~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/*
   - *~/Library/Messages/*
   - *~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imessage.bag.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.FaceTime.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.iMessage.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.ids.FaceTime.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.ids.iMessage.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.AIM.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.Jabber.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.LSSharedFileList.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.StatusMessages.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.Yahoo.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.plist*
4. Copy the following files and directories from your Time Machine backup to their respective locations on your new system:

   - *~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/*
   - *~/Library/Messages/*
   - *~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imessage.bag.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.FaceTime.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.iMessage.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.ids.FaceTime.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.ids.iMessage.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.AIM.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.Jabber.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.LSSharedFileList.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.StatusMessages.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.Yahoo.plist
     ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.plist*
5. Restart your system

Comment: Seems reasonable enough and the process makes sense.  I'll give this a go in a virtual instance and go from there.  Looks very promising.  Thanks!

Comment: No luck using this method in macOS 10.12.

Comment: Correction: had success on Sierra after a second attempt.

Comment: @MichaelAhlers If things are different on Sierra, can you add a new answer describing the necessary steps?

Comment: awesome, worked a treat on 10.12.4

Comment: this is not working in 10.13 (for me). any other suggestions? i've tried this several times; also deleted/moved over other "messages" preference files & container folders. after each restart, the system seems to be replacing my 150MB chat.db with a 4KB one. i've also tried putting the archive folder directly in the messages library folder & aliased it to the container like attachments etc is, but no success :-(

Comment: Can confirm this no longer works on `macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E202)`

Comment: Worked like a charm with macOS 11.5.2

Comment: Worked on macOS 13.3.1.

Answer (score -2):

To make it work on High Sierra prior to 10.13.5:

1. [Download this file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/balupton/3d29aa6d3c5dd5b17928035f3e8eebf7/raw/b913586a5fee19b7915455377aa1213e1f12a1bb/restore-messages.bash)
2. Open terminal and run `chmod +x restore-messages.bash`
3. Restart your machine
4. Open terminal and run `./restore-messages.bash "the path to your backup user directory"`
5. Restart your machine
6. Open messages

Based on the [`macup` command](https://github.com/balupton/dotfiles/blob/master/.scripts/commands/macup) from [my dotfiles](https://github.com/balupton/dotfiles)

---

To make it work on High Sierra 10.13.5 and later, the process has become automatic and builtin thanks to iCloud Messages.

Open the Messages App ➡️ `Preferences` ➡️ `Accounts` tab  ➡️ check `Enable Messages in iCloud`

[image: Screenshot of how to open Messages Preferences]

[image: Screenshot of how to enable Messages in iCloud]

Comment: No, if you enable Messages in iCloud what happens is that messages are lost on _all devices_, not just one.