# My mail rules don't stay on

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

I've setup one very simple rule that applies to messages from one sender... the rule works just like it should (most of the time).

Randomly, after I've restarted Mail the rule will be unchecked, so all of the new emails that were supposed to have been moved aren't. So I dutifully go i and check it back on when this happens, and drag the emails where they belong. this started when I up graded to Mavericks (a week or two after it was released). It has become very irritating by now, and I wanted to know if anybody else has had this problem and found a solution, or if somebody has a suggestion on what I could do to keep that rule checked off!

Comment: What kind of mail are you using? GMail? Custom domain? Microsoft Exchange?

Comment: I'm seeing the same - I have several rules, and they all get disabled for no obvious reason. Very annoying.

Comment: I'm using a gmail account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mavericks Mail will not save preferences](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110334/mavericks-mail-will-not-save-preferences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your Mail preferences are not saved.

Try this (it is not same as using Disk Utility to repair permissions)

> You can use the ACL tool on the Recovery HD to do this:
>
> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD using ⌘R.
> 2. Run `resetpassword` in Terminal (available from Utilities → Terminal).
> 3. Select your account from the drop-down list.
> 4. Click the Reset button for **Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs**.

<sup>Source: grgarside — https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110346/</sup>

If you are not comfortable doing it above way, there is a application called [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/downloadonyx.php) that will do it for you (and much more).

[image: repair ACL]

Comment: I'll give that a try as soon as I get a chance...

Comment: It seems to have worked!

Comment: Problem with user permissions unfortunately Disk Utility doesn't (give the opportunity to) repair those.

Comment: Please give attribution and use quote formatting when copying information from other answers.

Comment: @grgarside sorry about that, was not intentional, will pay more attention in the future