# All apps unresponsive in iMac

Tags: applications, imac

All Apps on my iMac are completely unresponsive. The only one working is Safari.
I tried to repair the volume, repair disk permission, PRAM reset, clearing all caches, running periodic scripts.

The Apps show a UI and load it (i.e. the App Store reloads it's content), but there is no way to interact.

Comment: did you try to log in a other (guest) user ?

Comment: yes, I did and it worked without any problrm

Comment: But the problem in the main user account still exist.

Comment: so your account is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, running a permissions fix on the hard drive with Disk Utility will not check or fix the permissions of user accounts, and instead will only tackle faults with system file and application access.

You need to repair your home folder (user) since the other user works.

Reset Home Folder permissions and ACLs Error

[Follow the instructions here.](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22861162#22861162)

[or more clear here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110346/46541)